# How to disable all Cortex services

Tags: configuration, cortex

I want to disable all Cortex services in my 10.2 XP1 environment.

I am getting the following in the log `Connection string 'cortex.processing.engine' is not found.` Because there is no `Cortex Processing engine`, and thus no `connection string`, but I don't know how to configure my instance so that it does not look for that `connection string` and any others relating to `Cortex`.

Here's the full error:

```
11788 13:42:56 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/PageEditbar/PageEditBar.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
   at ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/QuickBar/QuickBar.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.PageEditBar.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.ControlsExtension.PageEditBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper)
   at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_ExperienceEditor_PageEditbar_PageEditBar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\websites\site.cm\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditBar.cshtml:line 4
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/QuickbarButton/QuickbarButton.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.RenderItem(TextWriter output, Item item)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickBar.QuickBar.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickBar.ControlsExtension.QuickBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering)
   at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_QuickBar_QuickBar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\websites\site.cm\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\QuickBar\QuickBar.cshtml:line 4
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.TypeInitializationException
Message: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase' threw an exception.
Source: Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.GetProcessComponentState()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.PreRender()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonIconButtonBase.PreRender()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickbarButton.ControlsExtension.QuickbarButton(Controls controls, Rendering rendering)
   at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_QuickbarButton_QuickbarButton_cshtml.Execute() in d:\websites\site.cm\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\QuickbarButton\QuickbarButton.cshtml:line 4
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.TypeInitializationException
Message: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestRepository' threw an exception.
Source: Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestRepository..ctor()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase..cctor()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject[T](XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestRepository.Get()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestRepository..cctor()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Message: Connection string 'cortex.processing.engine' is not found.
Source: Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Client
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Client.WebApiProcessingEngineClient.EnsureConnectionString(String name)
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Client.WebApiProcessingEngineClient.CreateHttpClient()
   at Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Client.WebApiProcessingEngineClient..ctor(ILogger`1 logger)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Requests.ExperienceEditor.ShowSuggestedPersonalizationDialogRequest..ctor()
```

Comment: What version of sitecore are you running and what topology?

Comment: Sitecore 10.2 XP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore has only one OOTB feature that uses ***Cortex*** and it is **Personalization Suggestions** in **ContentTesting**.

If you do not use Content Testing, you can disable it with setting in `Sitecore.ContentTesting.config`:

```
<setting name="ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled" value="false" />
```

If it does not help, try to disable `Sitecore.ContentTesting.*` configs.

P.S. Almosl all Cortex references are related to *Processing* server role, but `ContentTesting` is linked to many roles: *ContentManagement, ContentDelivery, Reporting, Processing*. Keep this in mind as you use scaled topology.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I checked about `Cortex` and according to `Sitecore`, the `Cortex` is machine learning within `Sitecore` and built on top of the `Sitecore experience Database`. `Cortex` will analyze any data within `XDB`. Cortex analyzes this data and provides insights to you.

The `Sitecore Cortex™ Processing Tasks` database temporarily stores tasks to be processed by the `Sitecore Cortex Processing Engine service`.

When I checked in the `Sitecore 10.2` Vanilla instance and found that we need to specify these two settings to make it work.

```
 <add name="cortex.processing.engine" connectionString="https://sitecore10.2xconnect.dev.local" />
 
 <add name="cortex.processing.engine.client.certificate" connectionString="StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=3C31AAA842C89FE22C629525FAE49A8BFE67614F" />
```

So the reason maybe you don't have these in your `Connection String`. So if you can verify and use this, then I think the error will go.

The `Thumbprint` used in the `cortex.processing.engine.client.certificate`, the key needs to be matched with the `validateCertificateThumbprint` value given in the `yourxconnectinstance\App_Config\AppSettings.config` with this.

```
<add key="validateCertificateThumbprint" value="3C31AAA842C89FE22C629525FAE49A8BFE67614F" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds like you're saying that it can't be disabled? Not the answer I was hoping for, but I would like to have a definitive answer, if possible.

Comment: This is all interesting and potentially useful but doesn't directly answer my question. My question was, "How do I disable Cortex services?" Your answer would be useful if I wanted to use Cortex, but was getting the reported error.

Answer (score 0):

We have had the exact same issue after upgrading to Sitecore 10.3.

`ContentTesting.AutomaticContentTesting.Enabled` was also set to `false`, however this exception still threw up.

This was 'resolved' by setting a false connection string, but this was of course not the desired solution:

```
<add name="cortex.processing.engine" connectionString="https://notused" />
```

After consulting Sitecore Support this could be resolved by removing the `Optimization.ShowSuggestedPersonalization` in `App_Config\Sitecore\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.config`.

The following Patch file can be used to get this fixed:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <!-- Remove Optimization.ShowSuggestedPersonalization to prevent issues with Experience Editor when there is no Cortex Processing Engine set up -->
      <sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>
          <request name="Optimization.ShowSuggestedPersonalization" type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Requests.ExperienceEditor.ShowSuggestedPersonalizationDialogRequest, Sitecore.ContentTesting">
              <patch:delete />
          </request>
     </sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```